# get tab's socket instance on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have to get socket instance in my ajax request on server in node.js module. Here is my code.

***app.js***

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshake, callback) { 
   if (handshake.headers.cookie) {
       cookieParser(handshake, null, function(err) {
           handshake.sessionID = handshake.signedCookies['express.sid'];
       });
   } else { return callback('No cookie transmitted.', false); }
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
    var session = socket.handshake.session;
    var userid = session.userid;   
    socket.join("room");
    //make user offline 

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        //my code goes here...
        //make user offline 
    })
});
```

Now in one of my ajax request, I want socket instance

```
app.post('/logout', function (req, res) { 
   //here i want socket instance, so I can emit message to all socket, accept this.
});
```

As I know, each tab creates it's own new socket connection, but session is unique between all tabs of browser. So, How Do I store socket for each tab on server side, where I can find easily socket instance, and then broadcast message to all sockets, excluding that socket which is creating events. (means user's active tab's socket connection)

any guess.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my app, I can do what you say because i use namespace and room and so in a room i can find every socket of someone.

```
io.of('/user').clients(idRoom);
```

So that i can remove every socket of the user. But if you cannot use this, i think in your app you will have to implement outside socket.io a class for someone (using session as a way to see if it's already have a socket open or if you have to create a new instance). And in this class, have a socket table so that you will be able to handle socket of someone.

In my case, i do the same except that i use the room of socket.io to do that.

And to broadcast to every socket, it depends what is your app. If your app send to anyone in the same namespace, it doesn't change anything because the socket of the same session will also receive the message. But if not, you will have to implement a function to emit to every socket of the table i suggested above.
In my case i use the 'exclude' to ensure the current socket doesn't receive the message but usually you can use broadcast.

```
io.of('/user').in(this.id).except(socket.id).emit('msg', { text: text,type:person});
```

To conclude, socket.io will not help you to handle session and several socket for one user/session but you can manage to deal with it using room feature (in my case it was the best way), or implement a user class where you will manage a table of your session sockets.